# In Ubuntu terminal ,how can I change the hash (#) into normal user($)?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu

In Ubuntu terminal ,how can I change the hash (#) into normal user($) ?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably logging-in as root, which should be avoided as much as possible.

You need to create a normal user account to login.

For commands that need root permissions, use the
[sudo command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows subsystem for Linux, you need to switch to normal user:

```
su $USER
```

You can create a normal user through the command:

```
adduser $USER
```